# Read multiple csv files in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, row

I have a set of text files like these:

file corresponding to ID `A`

```
<empty line>
#-----------------------------------------
#    foo  bar  baz  
#-----------------------------------------
    0.0120932       1.10166       1.08745 
    0.0127890       1.10105       1.08773 
    0.0142051       1.09941       1.08760 
    0.0162801       1.09662       1.08548 
    0.0197376       1.09170       1.08015
```

file corresponding to ID `B`

```
<empty line>
#-----------------------------------------
#    foo  bar  baz  
#-----------------------------------------
    0.888085      0.768590      0.747961
    0.893782      0.781607      0.760417
    0.899830      0.797021      0.771219
    0.899266      0.799260      0.765859
    0.891489      0.781255      0.728892
```

etc.

I want to read all of them into a `pandas` dataframe, whose columns are `['ID', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. The ID doesn't correspond to the file name, but this is a detail: just imagine there's a mapping available (e.g., a dictionary) from file names to IDs.

Usually, when I want to create a dataframe row by row, I read each row as a dictionary and append to a list, then convert the list of dictionaries to a dataframe. However, this trick doesn't work here, because each dictionary contains more than one row. How can I solve this? Concatenating multiple dataframes is quite slow, so I'd rather have a more performing solution.

EDIT: this is the pandas dataframe I want as an output (example based on the two files above);

```
    ID       foo      bar       baz
  0  A  0.012093  1.10166   1.08745
  1  A  0.012789  1.10105   1.08773
  2  A  0.014205  1.09941   1.08760
  3  A  0.016280  1.09662   1.08548
  4  A  0.019738  1.09170   1.08015
  5  B  0.888085  0.768590  0.747961
  6  B  0.893782  0.781607  0.760417
  7  B  0.899830  0.797021  0.771219
  8  B  0.899266  0.799260  0.765859
  4  B  0.891489  0.781255  0.728892
```

Comment: Quick note: "*Concatenating multiple dataframes is quite slow*" -> this is not true if you concatenate all at once, what is slow is to concatenate dataframes one by one in a python loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### updated answer

Using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `skiprows`, a custom separator and a dictionary of the ID:filename pairs (you could also use a list of tuples, a dictionary with filename:id pairs…). Then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the files into a single DataFrame:

```
files = {'A': 'A.csv', 'B': 'B.csv'}

names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
skip = 4
df = (pd.concat({k: pd.read_csv(v, skiprows=skip, sep=r'\s+', names=names)
                 for k,v in files.items()},
                names=['ID'])
        .reset_index('ID')
        #.reset_index(drop=True) # uncomment to have a clean index
    )
```

Output:

```
  ID       foo       bar       baz
0  A  0.012093  1.101660  1.087450
1  A  0.012789  1.101050  1.087730
2  A  0.014205  1.099410  1.087600
3  A  0.016280  1.096620  1.085480
4  A  0.019738  1.091700  1.080150
0  B  0.888085  0.768590  0.747961
1  B  0.893782  0.781607  0.760417
2  B  0.899830  0.797021  0.771219
3  B  0.899266  0.799260  0.765859
4  B  0.891489  0.781255  0.728892
```

##### original answer

Assuming your files are named `A.csv`/`B.csv` you can use a custom function and [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). In the function use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `skiprows`, a custom separator and provide the expected names:

```
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

files = glob('*.csv')
# or from an explicit list:
# files = ['A.csv', 'B.csv']

def read_file(path, skip=4, names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    stem = Path(path).stem
    return (stem,
            pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=skip, sep=r'\s+',
                        names=names)
              .assign(ID=stem)[['ID']+names]
            )

dfs = dict(map(read_file, files))
```

Variant with a function that returns a DataFrame (not a tuple) and taking the ID as parameter:

```
def read_file(path, id=None, skip=4, names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    return (pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=skip, sep=r'\s+',
                        names=names)
              .assign(ID=id)[['ID']+names]
            )

dfs = {(stem:=Path(f).stem): read_file(f, id=stem)
       for f in files}
```

Output:

```
{'A':   ID       foo      bar      baz
      0  A  0.012093  1.10166  1.08745
      1  A  0.012789  1.10105  1.08773
      2  A  0.014205  1.09941  1.08760
      3  A  0.016280  1.09662  1.08548
      4  A  0.019738  1.09170  1.08015,
 'B':   ID       foo       bar       baz
      0  B  0.888085  0.768590  0.747961
      1  B  0.893782  0.781607  0.760417
      2  B  0.899830  0.797021  0.771219
      3  B  0.899266  0.799260  0.765859
      4  B  0.891489  0.781255  0.728892}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but not there yet. 1) The file names don't contain the IDs (don't ask): I get them from somewhere else. For your purpose, you can assume to have access to a dict where the key is the file path, and the value is the ID (or viceversa).  I could still use your second variant, but at the end your solution returns a dictionary. Instead I want a dataframe. I will edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: "*The file names don't contain the IDs (don't ask): I get them from somewhere else*" then please be explicit, add this information to the question. Then the second approach can be used in combination with `concat` if you want a single DataFrame. I'll update the answer based on your edit.

Comment: Nowhere did I say the filenames would contain the IDs. Anyway, I'll add this to the question.

Comment: I didn't say you did, just that this information is missing to be able to give you an fully working code ;)

Comment: @DeltaIV see update, but I still have to make an assumption on how to get the ID

Comment: I'm writing a new question which derives from this one, you may have a look it if you have time :-)